# Magento: Setup cronjob every 2 hours

Tags: php, magento

For some reason this code in module's config.xml:

```
<jobs>
    <stockupdate>
       <schedule><cron_expr>0 */2 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
        <run><model>stockupdate/cron::start</model></run>
    </stockupdate>
</jobs>
```

doesn't work. Although after changing `*/2` to `*` all seems to be alright.

To test it I first do a `TRUNCATE cron_schedule`, then clean the cache `rm -rf var/cache` then run `php cron.php` and then `SELECT * FROM cron_schedule` to see if job was scheduled.

I know there is also the nasty way `0 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22 0 0 0` but this is a very inelegant solution.

So how I can tell Magento to run this task every 2 hours?

Comment: Although it doesn't make much sense, I just tested it. Doesn't work

Comment: `0/2` is the standard crontab syntax. I give a pass, as this really depends on how Magneto handle the crontab.

Comment: The standard crontab syntax is `*/2` like I tried to use the first time. see http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl5_crontab.htm (search for "every two hours")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

`<schedule><cron_expr>0 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>`

and have your code check for even hours.  Not elegant, but it would work.  If it needs to be configurable you could add a configuration option to control how often it runs in hours.

**Update:**

Look at `Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule` in the `matchCronExpression` method:

```
    // handle modulus
    if (strpos($expr,'/')!==false) {
        $e = explode('/', $expr);
        if (sizeof($e)!==2) {
            throw Mage::exception('Mage_Cron', "Invalid cron expression, expecting 'match/modulus': ".$expr);
        }
        if (!is_numeric($e[1])) {
            throw Mage::exception('Mage_Cron', "Invalid cron expression, expecting numeric modulus: ".$expr);
        }
        $expr = $e[0];
        $mod = $e[1];
    } else {
        $mod = 1;
    }

    // handle all match by modulus
    if ($expr==='*') {
        $from = 0;
        $to = 60;
    }
    // handle range
    elseif (strpos($expr,'-')!==false) {
        $e = explode('-', $expr);
        if (sizeof($e)!==2) {
            throw Mage::exception('Mage_Cron', "Invalid cron expression, expecting 'from-to' structure: ".$expr);
        }

        $from = $this->getNumeric($e[0]);
        $to = $this->getNumeric($e[1]);
    }
    // handle regular token
    else {
        $from = $this->getNumeric($expr);
        $to = $from;
    }

    if ($from===false || $to===false) {
        throw Mage::exception('Mage_Cron', "Invalid cron expression: ".$expr);
    }

    return ($num>=$from) && ($num<=$to) && ($num%$mod===0);
```

It is setup to handle */2 properly.

Comment: That's what I actually did already. But I posted the question here to find out maybe there is a way to have an every 2 hours task. Thanks anyway for posting.

Comment: Updated answer as I went and reviewed the cron/schedule Model

Comment: Sorry I can't look now on the Magento core to see the context of this code. I'm pretty sure that Magento handles properly the modulo expressions on the first argument of cron expression, i.e. minutes. What I am sure about, is that my tests failed on the second one - hours.

Comment: Keeping in mind that, can you tell if it really parses modulo only for minutes? I'd like too see for myself but another project's deadline is soon and I'm in a hurry. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

for every 2 hour use expression

```
<schedule><cron_expr>0 */2 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
```

if you set

```
<schedule><cron_expr>* */2 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
```

you will get, that task will be sheduled every minute each second hour. 60 tasks for second hour, 0 tasks for 3d hour, 60 tasks for 4 hour etc.

Comment: Я же также и поставил. I set it that way. Anyway, this is a very old question.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the cron task to * */02

Comment: This code `$e = explode('/', $expr); /*...*/ $expr = $e[0]; $mod = $e[1]; /*...*/ return /*...*/ && ($num%$mod===0);` (from the other question) will surely convert it to numeric value. Haven't tested it but I don't give it many chances. =/

Answer (score 0):

If you want every 2 hours, the expression would be:

```
<schedule>00 */2 * * *</schedule>
```

This will execute at minute 0 past every 2nd hour.

[Check for more expressions](https://crontab.guru/#00_*/2_*_*_*)